# Nodejs add less-cookie variable to the session

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

I use `cookieSession` with Express and I want to add information to the sessions without it being added to the cookie as well.

I suppose only the `sessionId` is necessary to be stored on the client, but I don't
understand how to add more information without it ending up in the cookie.

This is roughly what I want:

```
req.session.sessionId = "sessionId" -> in the cookiesession (It's work)
req.session.info2 = "info2" -> only linked to the session. (How to do this ?)
```

It is possible to add an object to the session without it being sent to the client?

Answer (score 2):

That's how `cookieSession` works: it stores all the session data in the cookie.

If you don't want this, you need to use the regular [`express.session`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) middleware (instead of `express.cookieSession`), but it will require you to use a session store because that data has to be stored *somewhere*.

You can use the default `MemoryStore` – which stores all the data in memory, meaning that it *will* be lost when your Node app is restarted – or use a more persistent solution, for instance using [`connect-redis`](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) to store session data in a Redis database.

If you just don't want the session data to be *visible*, there are also client-side session libraries that completely encrypt the data being stored in the cookie, so it isn't visible. One such library is [`node-client-sessions`](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions).

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, too bad for me. I have reached the limitation of cookies and I wanted to resolve my problem while maintaining the cookie-session functionality...

I must have to find another solution...

Comment: If you have really large cookies, perhaps [compression](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) might solve some of your problems.